# Connection String to an Azure Cloud Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

How do I make a connection string to a cloud storage account so I can access tables, blobs, and queues? Sample code appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

If you look in the Azure portal under the storage account in question, and look in the "Access Keys" item in the left-side nav, there it shows you the two provided keys and the entire connection string needed to access the storage account.

Answer (score 16):

Notating this because it's a top Google hit and the information is no longer current.

You can configure `CloudStorageAccount` via a connection string passed to `FromConfigurationSetting()`.

You build a configuration string per below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string

There's also a helper in the IDE if you right click on the Role.

Answer (score 15):

Reference: [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string#create-a-connection-string-for-an-azure-storage-account)

**Connection string to an Azure storage account:**

`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=[http|https];AccountName=myAccountName;AccountKey=myAccountKey`

***example:***

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storagesample;AccountKey=<account-key>
```

**Connection string to the storage emulator:**

config.xml

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
    </appSettings>

DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=testacc1;
AccountKey=1gy3lpE7Du1j5ljKiupgKzywSw2isjsdfdsfsdfsdsgfsgfdgfdgfd/YThisv/OVVLfIOv9kQ==;
BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:8440/testacc1;
TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:8440/testacc1;
QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:8440/testacc1;
```

Ex:

```
 <connectionStrings>      

    <add name="AzureStorageAccount" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=testdata;Accoun‌​tKey=1gy3lpE7Du1j5ljKiupgKzywSw2isjsdfdsfsdfsdsgfsgfdgfdgfd/YThisv/OVVLfIOv9kQ==;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

But sometimes it won't work and will through the error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll

Additional information: No valid combination of account information found.
```

then please try with below code: tested and working 100%

```
var accountName = "test2rdsfdg462";
var keyValue = "1gy3lpE7Du1j5ljKiupgKzywSfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdqGxd7/YThisv/OVVLfIOv9kQ==";
var useHttps = true;
var connValid = true;

var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, keyValue);
var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, useHttps);
var conString = storageAccount.ToString(connValid);

CloudStorageAccount sa = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
```

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft has a nice guide called **Connect an app to Azure Storage** that goes through everything you need.

Description:

> Create a simple application and add configuration, client library
> references, and code to connect it to Azure Storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/connect-an-app-to-azure-storage/

Step 7 there is **Connect to your Azure storage account**

Connection strings example:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={your-storage};
   AccountKey={your-access-key};
   EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

The REST endpoint is a combination of your storage account name, the data type, and a known domain. For example:

| Data type | Example endpoint |
| --- | --- |
| Blobs | https://[name].blob.core.windows.net/ |
| Queues | https://[name].queue.core.windows.net/ |
| Table | https://[name].table.core.windows.net/ |
| Files | https://[name].file.core.windows.net/ |

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/connect-an-app-to-azure-storage/7-connect-to-your-azure-storage-account

To get a connection string I usually follow @user3459730 example and copy it from Azure Portal. Go to Storage account -> Access keys, click on Show keys and copy the Connection string.

[image]